# javascript div disappear when input deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, hide

I have a question concerning the following :

I have a div with `display:none`. This div appears once a user types text into an input field (with the jQuery show() method). Everything works fine, but once I delete the text typed into the input field, I would like the DIV to disappear again. My attempt:

use another `function` with the jQuery `hide()` function if the input is empty, but it prevents the function using show() to be triggered (since the input is obviously empty by default).

Any ideas would be much appreciated !

Here is my script:

```
function password1Security()

{
var pwd1 = document.getElementById("password1");
var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{7,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
var pwdsft = document.getElementById("passwordSafetyLevel1");

{
if (strongRegex.test(pwd1.value)){pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:green;">Safe</span>'} else if (mediumRegex.test(pwd1.value)) 

{pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:orange;">Quite Safe</span>'} else {pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Unsafe</span>'};
}
};

function passSafetyAppear1()

{$("#passwordSafety1").show()};

function showPassSafety1()

{
password1Security();
passSafetyAppear1();
};

</script>

<input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" size="15" maxlength="20" style="width:500px; height:30px;" 

onKeyUp="showPassSafety1()"/>
<br/>

<span name="passwordSafety1" id="passwordSafety1" style="font-size:12pt; display:none;">Your password is <b 

name="passwordSafetyLevel1" id="passwordSafetyLevel1"></b>.</span><br/>
```

Thank you in advance,

Pierre

Comment: Share your actual script and markup.

Answer (score 1):

Do that operation on blur (when the input loses focus).  Use code like this with the proper selectors to achieve this:

```
$('input-selector').blur(function(){
    if(!$(this).val())
        $('div-selector').hide();
});
```

Comment: I have tried all three possibilities, but none have worked. Is there a possibility to check whether the user deletes what he typed into the input field ? I have searched for something like that, but so far without any success. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dmwFg/)**.

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) $('div').show();
    else $('div').hide();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input-selector').keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
           $('div-selector').show();
        else
           $('div-selector').hide();
});
```

Have a try...